# Unable to create correct JSON against csv file in Groovy within JSR Preprocessor

Tags: json, csv, groovy, jmeter

Complete noob in JMeter.Been trying create a json using CSV file with Groovy and pass the same in the request body in jmeter but unable to create the JSON in required format:

Sample2.csv

Work Registration - External,3423,115

> Jmeter    HTTPRequest    --JSR223Preprocessor

For above csv, the following code in JSR223Preprocessor provides output

```
import groovy.json.*
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()

@groovy.transform.Immutable
class WKList {
    String wkname
    int Wkid
    int numId
}

def WKLists = new File("Sample2.csv")
        .readLines()
        .collect { line ->
            new WKList(Integer.parseInt(line.split(",")[0]), Integer.parseInt(line.split(",")[1])),line.split(",")[2] }

builder(
        Place:'RA',
        Serial: 2,
        SerialDate: 'Dec 30 ,2021',
        WKList: WKLists.collect(),

)
log.info(builder.toPrettyString())
```

Output:
{
"Place": "RA",
"Serial": 2,
"SerialDate": "Dec 30 ,2021",
"WKList": [
{
"wkid": 3423,
"numId": 115,
"wkname": "Work Registration - External"
}
]
}

First 3 columns are hardcoded.
But if original csv file is as follows

RA,8,Dec 30, 2021,Work Registration - External,3423,233

KA,92,Dec 20, 2021,State Registration - Internal,121,3

How can the code be modified to include values from csv rather than fetching hard coded values as done earlier ? Also  if CSV Data Set Config JMeter is used, does it read per line for each user for each iteration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work for csv file line
RA,8,"Dec 30, 2021",Work Registration - External,3423,233

```
import groovy.json.*

class WKList {String wkname; int Wkid ;int numId}
List<WKList> WKDetList = new ArrayList<>();
def lines =new File("Sample2.csv").readLines()

def content = [:]
def articles = []
def article = [:]
for (int i=1;i<lines.size();i++)

{ 
String[] splitData = lines[i].split(',');

content.put('Place', splitData[0])
content.put('Serial', splitData[1])
content.put('SerialDate', splitData[2])
article.put('wkname', splitData[3])
article.put('wkid', splitData[4])
article.put('numId', splitData[5])
articles.add(article)
content.put('WKList', articles)   
  
}
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(content).toPrettyString(), '')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)


log.info(JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(content)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This line looks very suspicious:

```
new WKList(Integer.parseInt(line.split(",")[0]), Integer.parseInt(line.split(",")[1])),line.split(",")[2] }
```

Your `WKList` class takes a [String](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-3.0.7/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html) as a first parameter followed by 2 [Integers](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-3.0.7/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Integer.html)

So my expectation is that you should change it to something like:

```
new WKList(line.split(",")[0], Integer.parseInt(line.split(",")[1]), Integer.parseInt(line.split(",")[2]))
```

Also your code assumes the following CSV file structure:

```
Work Registration - External,3423,115
```

If you need to include use the following file format:

```
RA,8,Dec 30, 2021,Work Registration - External,3423,233
```

we need to know what is the "required format" of the JSON.

In the meantime you can get familiarized with the following material:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri ! Corrected the line. Expected output is :{
    "Place": "RA",
    "Serial": 2,
    "SerialDate": "Dec 30 ,2021",
    "WKList": [
        {
            "wkid": 3423,
            "numId": 115,
            "wkname": "Work Registration - External"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: If code sample to do above requirement can be posted, that would be most helpful

Comment: Can a sample be posted ?